# how to write a nested Sql query in Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, orm

so i have this query in sql:

```
select  (select ConfigItemDescripcion from SGRC_ConfigItem where ConfigId = 'SEGM' and ConfigItemId = SegmentoId) Segmento,
             (select ConfigItemDescripcion from SGRC_ConfigItem where ConfigId = 'MRCA' and ConfigItemId = MarcaId) Marca,
             Producto, 
             Familia
from sgrc_emisor 
where EmisorCuenta = '3702406435'
```

I want to write the same query in a linq expression or a lambda expression.

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i manage to come up with the query in linq, dont know how to do it in lambda, but it works fine.

```
 var obj = (from emisor in _context.DbSetEmisores
                       where emisor.EmisorCuenta == cuenta
                       select new EmisorDto
                       {
                           Segmento =
                           ((from itemConf in _context.ItemsDeConfiguracion
                             where itemConf.ConfigID == "SEGM" && itemConf.ConfigItemID == emisor.SegmentoId
                             select new { itemConf.ConfigItemDescripcion }).FirstOrDefault().ConfigItemDescripcion),
                           Marca =
                           ((from itemConf in _context.ItemsDeConfiguracion
                             where itemConf.ConfigID == "MRCA" && itemConf.ConfigItemID == emisor.MarcaId
                             select new { itemConf.ConfigItemDescripcion }).FirstOrDefault().ConfigItemDescripcion),
                           Producto = emisor.Producto,
                           Familia = emisor.Familia,
                           SegmentoId = emisor.SegmentoId,
                           MarcaId = emisor.MarcaId,
                       }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

When using LINQ you can use either Query syntax as shown in the LINQ below (If you are familiar with SQL then this looks more natural).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq

The other option is to use Method syntax, and below is a short example.  This allows for chaining of methods, biggest thing to keep in mind is "var" should be used, the return type is dynamic and the compiler will help you out a lot if you just use "var"

var items = _list.Where(x => x.Attribute1 == "NextField")
                .Where(x => x.Attribute2 == "Something else");

Other things that hangs folks up sometimes is LINQ uses "delayed execution"

Comment: Thanks for the help, but a i wanted an answer and not an example, it helped though dont get me mistaken.